# Excel Services permission error

Tags: 2007, permissions, excel-services

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

Some users are getting an error when trying to open a spreadsheet from the SharePoint.

```
You do not have permissions to open this file on Excel Services. Make sure that the file is in an Excel Services trusted location and that you have access to the file.
```

- This error is not displayed to administrators
- The users who see this error have Add, Edit and View permissions for the document library
- The users who see this error can open other spreadsheets within the document library

I have tried asking one of the users with this error to add the SharePoint's url to their list of trusted sites (Internet Explorer-->Tools-->Internet Options-->Security tab-->Trusted Sites-->Add) but this did not seem to make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Additional info:

- Enterprise features have been disabled (I was told to disable them as this subsite does not have the licenses to support it. I did not activate them in the first place)
- Using the drop down list, the user has the following options: view properties, edit properties, view in web browser, snapshot in Excel, sendto and workflows. They have these options for **both** spreadsheets they can open and those they can't.
- The view in web browser/snapshot options only show up for me on certain documents. This doesn't correspond to whether other users can open them **or** whether the document is .xsl or .xsls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution* It seems that even though the users had permission to edit the spreadsheets, they didn't have permissions to see them. I assumed that giving them permission to add to the folder, view the items, and edit the items that they would be able to see them…apparently not! Gave them all read permission as well and now they all work fine. Feel a bit silly I didn’t work it out earlier and I’m still not sure why they were able to open some and not others but hopefully we won’t be seeing that error again!

Answer (score 1):

Can they open it if they select edit in excel from the item menu? It sounds like the library has not been set up as a Trusted Location in Excel services settings in Central Administration. No libraries in 2007 have excel services enabled by default they must be manually added to the list in Central Administration.

Comment: I don't have access to Central Administration, I will see if I can ask someone about that. Wouldn't this affect all spreadsheets?

Comment: It will affect all spreadsheets unless the library they are located in is set as a Trusted location. Are they able to open it by selecting edit in excel from the drop-down menu.

Comment: I've asked them to have a look so hopefully they will reply tomorrow. By just clicking on the name of the spreadsheet they can open some and not others :S

Comment: No they can't. I have added an update to my original question

Comment: It sounds like they have the Enterprise Features activated at the site collection level. You should not see the view in browser and snapshot if enterprise features are not activated. Something else to check, are all the spreadsheets .xslx or just .xsl?

Comment: I've e-mailed them to see if they will change the default open behaviour so hopefully that will help. We have a mix .xsl and .xslx and it doesn't seem to have an impact on the error

Comment: I finally have enough rep to vote you up, thanks for your help